# How to implement overlayfs in RAM

Tags: overlayfs

I have Ubuntu installed on an SSD and would like to use it as a customized live USB, allowing me to test system changes without risking corruption. I've read that Ubuntu uses overlayfs for this purpose, but I couldn't find the responsible script for my reference.

Could someone please guide me through the process of setting up my Ubuntu installation to function like a customized live USB using overlayfs? I understand that this may make the SSD unwritable without reformatting, and I'm willing to proceed with that understanding.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `overlayroot` package. Locate and read the manual for safe operation.

Comment: this is not good enough: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434508/creating-a-customized-ubuntu-live-usb-with-read-only-filesystem-squashfs-greater  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a customized Ubuntu Live USB with read-only filesystem squashfs greater than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434508/creating-a-customized-ubuntu-live-usb-with-read-only-filesystem-squashfs-greater)